Getting a rip while debugging a game
i downloaded bf1 from fitgirl repack and it didn't work it just shows me a black screen on launch then it won't respond
here the problem
I tried all solutions and none of them worked so i finally downloaded a debugger to see what's causing this problem here the debug anyway i remembered that i don't know thing about assembly can anyone help me ?
